# $(document).on doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refactor my old **JavaScript + jQuery** code. so I'm separating them to small chunks for easier maintenance.

In my old "procedural" code, the `(document).on()` method worked on every element. But now it only works on the first element.

```
Dnianas.Post = {



    init: function() {
        this.cache();
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    cache: function() {
        this.postForm = $('#postForm');
        this.likeButton = $('#likePost');
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $(document).on('submit', this.postForm, this.createPost);
    },

    createPost: function(event) {
        var request = $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/posts/create',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $loading.show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $loading.hide();
            }
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
            self.renderCreatedPost(data);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    },
```

Here is my code for posting text to the database. and when I send the request, No data will pass to the server. Nothing.

And here is my old code, That worked.

```
$body.on('submit', '#postForm', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/posts/create',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $loading.show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $loading.hide();
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.success == 'false') {
            // Render some error
        } else {
            // Post it
            }
        });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I don't know why, can someone explain this?

Like I said in my old code, It worked perfectly!

Comment: You'd have to post a **complete** example, including how you call those functions. Also mention what errors you see in the browser's error console, if any.

Comment: I just call `Dnianas.Post.init()` in my footer. Everything is self explained.

There are not any errors in my console. data is not passed and that's it.

Comment: You probably do well to a) remove all the code from this example that doesn't directly relate to `document.on()`, b) post the code that calls this and maybe any HTML that's important, and c) see if `document.on("submit"` is not catching the submit event or if it's doing the wrong thing once it catches the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's ever been a version of jQuery that supported what you're doing in the new code.

Your code is calling `cache`, then `bindEvents`. You have this in `cache`:

```
this.postForm = $('#postForm');
```

and this in `bindEvents`:

```
$(document).on('submit', this.postForm, this.createPost);
```

So that means you're calling `on` and passing it an event name, a jQuery object, and a function.

Looking at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on), there's no signature of `on` that allows a jQuery object as the second argument.

I see that you've now posted your old code, which was using a selector string there, which does indeed work via event delegation:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#postForm', this.createPost);
```

If you want to handle the submit on the element itself without using delegation, then of course it would be:

```
this.postForm.on('submit', this.createPost);
```